# What's the best way to organize my USB stick for PenDriveLinux and regular data?

Tags: ubuntu, portable, usb-flash-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on my new 32 Gb USB Stick, but I also want to keep a fair amount of space available for Portable Apps or general data transmissions.

When I tried to install Ubuntu using PenDriveLinux, it asked me if I wanted to format and partition my USB stick, but I guessed I'd first ask here before experimenting any further.

So what should I do? **Should I partition my USB stick or should I just leave it as one partition or make several?**

Note that I should be able to use this with Windows computers and the file system has to be accessible from Windows 7, so I guess it has to stay NTFS. And bonus points if you can advise me how to add Hiren's BootCD and/or UBCD into the mix

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should partition it since it's likely you'll have problems using Ubuntu on NTFS. I'd suggest keeping a chunk for Portable Apps, and deciding if you want to use FAT32 or NTFS on that partition. FAT32 is better supported under Linux, but has a 4GB file size limit. I'm not sure if any of your portable apps has a requirement for NTFS, but they should run without problems on FAT32.

Comment: Lol if I need to use FAT32, I would need like 4 partitions just for my data...

Comment: Maybe, but remember that it's 4 GB **file** size limit. So unless you carry your data in large encrypted containers or as `.iso` files...